# Deleting rows based on a column value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check if a cell ("C") does not contain a date or is empty to delete the specific row. My code does not delete all the specifics rows  and seems too slow for the number of rows (138).

```
lastrow = pertes.Cells(pertes.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Not IsDate(pertes.Cells(i, 3).Value) Or IsEmpty(pertes.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
        pertes.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: If you delete or add rows your loop must be backwards:  `For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1` otherwise deleting changes row count and therefore the loop counts wrong.

Comment: Great it's working @Pᴇʜ. How about the fact that it's slow?

Comment: See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete or add rows one-by-one your loop must be backwards:

```
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
```

otherwise deleting changes row count and therefore the loop counts wrong.

---

To make it faster you can collect all rows that have to be deleted in a range using `Union()`, and then delete them all at once in the end. This is faster because every delete action takes its time, and it reduces the amount of actions to 1.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = pertes.Cells(pertes.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim RowsToDelete As Range '… to collect all rows

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To LastRow 'forward or backward loop possible
        If Not IsDate(pertes.Cells(i, 3).Value) Or IsEmpty(pertes.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then 'collect first row
                Set RowsToDelete = pertes.Rows(i)
            Else 'add more rows to that range
                Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, pertes.Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    RowsToDelete.Delete 'delete all rows at once
End Sub
```

Note that here we don't need to loop backwards because we delete all rows at once *after* the loop.